# How can I create routes similar to Auth::routes()

Tags: laravel, routes

I created a laravel package with routes. I want to do something similar to Laravel's authentication scaffolding `Auth::routes()`, where they are injected into whatever file you want to include them (i.e. `api.php` or `web.php`).

I am currently using

```
public function boot()
{
    ...
    $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/api.php');
    ...
}
```

But this makes the routes available from anywhere, which I do not want.
I understand I should use a `Service Container`, but this is my first package and first time creating my own Service Provider, so I am not too sure how to do so, and I couldn't find documentation on how to use these for routes.

Instead, I want to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
//routes/api.php
Route::group(['prefix'=>'v1', 'middleware:auth-api'], function(){
    Logging::routes(); //<-----
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution, make a class that has a static method that declares your routes.

```
// your/package/Logging.php

class Logging
{
    public static method routes()
    {
        ...your routes...
    }
}

// routes/web.php

use Your/Package/Logging;

Logging::routes();
```

Comment: I mean, this works...Not what I was going for but there were no other suggestions.